# Did Mace Windu use the Force to command the reek to attack Jango Fett?

Tags: star-wars, attack-of-the-clones, mace-windu

Mace Windu was able to kill Jango Fett in the [Petranaki arena](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Petranaki_arena) on Geonosis after a [reek](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Reek) charged Fett and disabled his jetpack. **Is there any evidence that the reek's charge on Fett was caused by Windu using the Force to control it, or was the reek's charge a chance event in Windu's favor?**

For reference, here's a Youtube video of the scene in question:

I don't see any visual indication that Windu controlled the reek with the Force. Also, it doesn't look like he thought to do it at any point in the battle since Windu avoided the reek by running away from it (rather than controlling it) when the reek charged *him*. Is there any evidence from, say, the novelization?

Note: Answers must cite canon source(s). Legends sources are welcomed and appreciated as an optional supplement, but Legends-only answers are unacceptable.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

All signs point to no. Mace was unable to control the reek when it attacked him and was otherwise occupied a few seconds later.

> ***The reek followed Mace, and he had to slash wildly to fend it off. He
> did manage to drive it back, but was butted and lost his lightsaber in
> the process.** He came up facing the reek, and figured that he could
> outmaneuver it to get his weapon back easily enough, but then an
> armored rocket-man flew down in his path, blaster leveled.*
>
> ***Mace reached out with the Force and brought his lightsaber flying to
> his hand, moving like lightning to parry Jango’s first shot.** With the
> second shot, Mace was more in control, and his parry sent the bolt
> right back at the bounty hunter. But Jango was already in motion,
> diving sidelong and coming around ready to launch a series of shots
> the Jedi’s way.*
>
> *He was stopped by the reek. **Unable to distinguish friend from foe, the
> reek bore down on Jango.** He scored a couple of hits, but they hardly
> slowed the beast, and he was tossed away. The reek charged him, trying
> to stomp him as he rolled about desperately. Jango was fast, though.
> Every time he came around, he fired again, and again, his bolts
> burrowing into the furious reek’s belly.*
>
> <sub><sup>[Attack of the Clones: Official Novelisation](http://starwars.wikia.com/wiki/Star_Wars_Episode_II:_Attack_of_the_Clones_(novel))</sup></sub>